# How do you make a Div do the same thing as a a button?

Tags: html, button, menu, dropdown

I am trying to make a navigation bar for a project and I need a button to call the function for a dropdown menu. If I have a button, I can't format it the same as a div, and it stands out from the other options. Is there a way to make a div be a button? I have tried putting the onclick attribute on it, but then the drop-down menu doesn't appear in the same spot. Thanks in advance.

(I am very new to coding, so try to explain things in simple terms)

**I decided to do a hover drop-down menu which makes things a lot easier, but thank you for your answers!**

Comment: Please provide all relevant code that you have.

Comment: Every element can eventually styled like any other element... :) So yes, please provide the code. A click handler is the key.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are very new to coding.  Have you read about jquery at all?  I would definitely suggest it.  It is very possible to make things happen when a `<div>` tag is clicked with jquery functions.  Here is an example:

```
$("#IdOfDivTag").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```

You will have to add an id or class attribute to the div tag you want an action to happen with (unless you want the same action for all `<div>`, in which case you can use "div" in the jquery statement).

To implement jquery you need at add a jquery library to your code... You can start here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. One is to use jQuery (a Javascript extension), like [Branden Keck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976543/branden-keck) showed it to you. Another way is to use only html and Javascript: There is a html attribute which creates an Javascript event:

```
<div id="myDiv" onclick="clickEvent()">Some text</div>
```

clickEvent has to have brackets in it because it's a Javascript Function. Your Javascript could look like something like this then:

```
function clickEvent() {
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Here a snippet for that:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Hello World without jQuery!";
}

$("#myDiv2").click(function() {
  $("#myDiv2").html("Hello World with jQuery!");
});

$("#myDiv3").click(function() {
  $("#hiddenDiv").slideToggle(750); // 750 is the sliding time in ms
});
```

```css
#myDiv,
#myDiv2, #myDiv3, #hiddenDiv {
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5 all;
  font-family: "Arial";
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;  
  border-left: 1px groove #f0f0f0;
  border-top: 1px groove #f0f0f0;
}
#myDiv:hover,
#myDiv2:hover, #myDiv3:hover {
  background: #ffffff;

  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.22em;
  box-shadow: 0.22em 0.22em 0.44em #000000;
}
#myDiv2, #myDiv3 {
  background: #ff0000;
}

#hiddenDiv {
  background: #00aa00;
  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" onclick="myFunction()">Click this div! Without jQuery</div>
<div id="myDiv2">Click this div! With jQuery</div>

<div id="myDiv3">Toggle hidden Text With jQuery<span style="font-size: 0.7em;font-family:Arial;font-style:italic;"> May lag because of snippet.</span></div>

<div id="hiddenDiv">You found me!</div>
```